# Why is SLIME throwing these errors?

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

So I have been trying to learn Lisp lately. Unfortunately, nothing seems to work - I am following [this Common Lisp tutorial](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html) but when I tried to run `(hello-world)` a second time, instead of doing the same thing it gave me an error (Which I lost, because I didn't think to save it) about how `CL-USER>` was an undefined variable. I have never typed `CL-USER>` into SLIME, but that IS what the prompt is. I restarted EMACS and SLIME (Closed the window, that is) and restarted it. However, upon tryig to use the `(load "name")` method, it gave me the following error:

```
Compiler warnings for "helloworld.cl" :
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 43: Undeclared free variable CL-USER>
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 52: Undeclared free variable CL-USER>
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 58: Undeclared free variable ..\sOURCECODELISP\hELLOWORLD.CL
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 161: Undeclared free variable CL-USER>
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 278: Undeclared free variable CL-USER>
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 389: Undeclared free variable CL-USER>
Read error between positions 441 and 450 in f:/Lispbox/helloworld.cl.; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR #x2100B925AD>.
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT: After closing it, going to my next few classes, then staying after school, the problem persists, but now it just complains that `CL-USER>` is not a defined variable.

FYI, I originally attempted to load my file from `..\sourcecode\Lisp\helloworld.cl` because that's where I put it at first. I forgot quotes around it, so that may have caused the problem.

Comment: What are the contents of "helloworld.cl" exactly?

Comment: Did you accidentally save the REPL buffer as "helloworld.cl", instead of the buffer where you wrote the code?

Comment: @RainerJoswig IIRC it was a simple 'hello world' function, defined as follows: `(defun hello-world() (format t "Hello, ") (format t "World!"))` because I wanted to have more than 1 statement inside it.

Comment: @molbdnilo How would I check? I may have done that, what with never having used Emacs before and all. How would I differentiate?

Comment: Why the downvote? Just downvoting a question without giving any explanation is useless; it's better to tell the user how to fix it, or suggest an edit. Keep in mind, when someone asks a stupid question, they are often just learning the subject - Like I am about lisp, emacs and slime. You'll help the site by providing feedback. Of course, feel free to still downvote, but at least explain it.

Comment: @NickHartley Sounds like you solved it. Exellent. Learning Emacs *and* Slime *and* Lisp at the same time can feel like a bit much at times. Totally worth it, though.

Comment: @molbdnilo I did indeed, and it SO is. Unfortunately, I now have to manually dig through everything in the buffer, looking for the code that exeuted properly. Do you know of an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you copied code from an interactive session to the file `helloworld.cl`, you should have removed the prompts and interaction messages.

Comment: How would I have gone about doing that? I haven't used Emacs before, and for those like me, this answer will not be useful at all. Oh, and I was saving it via the key chord, not copy/pasting the code from the window.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that and get back to you. EDIT: That worked! Is there any way to only copy what I typed, and what executed correctly?